# how to create two buttons within form and have only one submit form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a "next" button and a "back" button in my form.  I want the "next" button to validate and submit the form.  And I want the "back" button to simply go back to the "cart" page.  But the "back" button keeps validating and trying to submit the form.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Cart")"><button class = "button" id = "back">Back</button></a>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" class="button" />
</div>
```

The reason I need the back link to be a button is so that it will look the same as the "next" button.  Any ideas how I can get this working correctly?

Comment: A simplest solution would be to not to have a button inside thr anchor but rather style the anchor so that it looks like a button.

Comment: you can also use PostBackURL for the back button...

Comment: @WiktorZychla I tried to style the anchor the same, but I could not get the height to be the same, so it looked funny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<button>` element always submits the form.  The same goes for a `<input type="submit" />` element.

**But a `<input type="button" />` will not submit the form.** That's what you want.

```
<div class="buttons">
    <input type="button" class="button" id="back" onclick="window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Cart")';">Back</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" class="button" />
</div>
```

**Edit** I'm not sure if you can put that inside an `<a>` element though. I reworked my example to use click events rather than a link. If it is valid to put inside a `<a>` element (can anyone confirm?), you can do it like that as well.

Comment: I got TypeError: window.href is undefined using the code above.  But sticking inside an <a> element did work for me. Thank you for the tip about the input type of button.  Didn't know that will not submit.

Comment: it had to be `window.location`; my mistake. But good to know wrapping it in an `<a>` works as well :)